# Create nested list of tuple elements based on the string integer number as index

Tags: python, tuples, sublist

Let’s say I have a tuple, which contains lists, where its first element is always a string-number, e.g.

```
asdf = (['0', ...], ['1', ...], ['2', ...], ['3.0', ...], ['3.1', ...], ['3.2', ...], ['4', ...] , ['5.0', ...], ['5.1', ...])
```

Baiscally, I want to have a list, which contains all the string-number of the lists of the tuple.

However, if the first value of each list contains a subindex (in this case `3.0, 3.1, 3.2 and 5.0, 5.1`) I want to put these subvalues together into a sublist. The result in this example should look like the following.

```
Result = ['0', '1', '2', ['3.0', '3.1', '3.2'], '4', ['5.0', '5.1']]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why `'0'` is not included in `Result`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby),

```
import operator
import itertools

tuples = (['0', ], ['1', ], ['2', ], ['3.0', ], ['3.1', ], ['3.2', ], ['4', ] , ['5.0', ], ['5.1', ])

l = map(operator.itemgetter(0), tuples)
# ['0', '1', '2', '3.0', '3.1', '3.2', '4', '5.0', '5.1']

results = list()
for name, group in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x:x.split('.')[0]):
    tmp_list = list(group)
    results.append(tmp_list[0] if len(tmp_list)==1 else tmp_list)

print(results)
# Output
['0', '1', '2', ['3.0', '3.1', '3.2'], '4', ['5.0', '5.1']]
```

Comment: Why the extraneous commas inside the lists in the definition of `tuples`?

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I removed `...` from the question `asdf = (['0', ...], ['1', ...], ...` so as to run my machine.

Comment: That basically works, however, if a number is equal/larger than 10, it will be also put into a sublist because the length will be checked and not the fact that there is a '.' in the string.

Comment: @eljobso, I changed `key` to `key=lambda x:x.split('.')[0]`. It should work as well for the case you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am not really familiar with the itertools so far. I definitly need to get more into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without using `itertools.groupby()`. You can use a sorting method/defaultdict approach like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

asdf = (['0', ], ['1', ], ['2', ], ['3.0', ], ['3.1', ], ['3.2', ], ['4', ] , ['5.0', ], ['5.1', ])

all_items = [x[0] for x in asdf]

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in all_items:
    key = item[0]
    d[key].append(item)

values = [x[1] for x in sorted(d.items())]

result = []
for lst in values:
    if len(lst) == 1:
        result.append(lst[0])
    else:
        result.append(lst)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['0', '1', '2', ['3.0', '3.1', '3.2'], '4', ['5.0', '5.1']]
```

This is also possible without defaultdicts too.